# Electrum SSL Cert Prorblem

Tags: bitcoind, electrum, ssl

İn electrum's site;

> Create a file that contains only the private key:
>
> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- your private key
>   -----BEGIN END KEY-----
>
> Set the path to your the private key file with setconfig:
>
> electrum setconfig ssl_privkey /path/to/ssl.key
>
> Create another file, file that contains your certificate, and the list
>   of certificates it depends on, up to the root CA. Your certificate
>   must be at the top of the list, and the root CA at the end.
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- your cert
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- intermediate cert
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- root cert
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> Set the ssl_chain path with setconfig:
>
> electrum setconfig ssl_chain /path/to/ssl.chain

I'm working on localhost only. I created a self-signed cert. I have ".key" and ".crt" files. **But have not a ".chain" file?**

How can I come from above? Thx...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out cert.chain -keyout key.pem
```

The cert itself is one CA added to the chain from the above command.
A .chain file is just a concatenation of signed ca certs